# link_to passes arguments to checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I successfully learnt how to use has_many :through with checkboxes from [this blog](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/).

Now I want to have some of these checkboxes checked, based on arguments passed with link_to.

I tried many different things like...

```
<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path, :category_ids => [1, 3] %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path(:category_ids => [1, 3]) %>
```

Something like that is a good start, now in your template, where you're adding the checkboxes, just add a small if that checks if there's a category_ids key in `params` and you should be good to go: `(params[:category_ids] || {}).include?(1)` where 1 is the number you want to check.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did it slightly differently - in the Posts controller I added @post.category_ids = (params[:category_ids])